# Web Application edit form prefilling and can't change form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, react-forms

I am attempting to prefill my react.js web application and also being able to edit the form details if I needed. I am using a PATCH method for this operation.

```
const [putName, setName] = useState('Initial Value');
const handleChangeName = e => {
    setName(e.detail.value);
};
```

```
<FormField label="Task Name">

<Input
   type="text"
   value={data.TaskName}
   onChange={handleChangeName}
   placeholder="Task Name"
/>
</FormField>
```

The issue is that I can't type into the form and when I try to update the form the empty fields are clearing the previous results.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate your state with the fetched value like this so that your changes will be reflected

```js
const [putName, setName] = useState(data?.TaskName ?? 'Initial Value');
const handleChangeName = e => {
    setName(e.detail.value);
};

<FormField label="Task Name">

<Input
   type="text"
   value={putName}
   onChange={handleChangeName}
   placeholder="Task Name"
/>
</FormField>
```